# Leitura ficheiro txt para memória

Tags: c

Estou a tentar ler o ficheiro que contém apenas 3 elementos.

- Nome do utilizador: Utilizador X
- Sexo do utilizador: Masculino ou feminino
- Idade do utilizador: X idade

O código que tenho neste momento é o seguinte:

```
FILE* fp;
char linha[500];

fp = fopen("Ficheiro Teste.txt","r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Empty Text File!\n");
}
else
{
    while(fp != EOF)
    {
        fgets(linha,sizeof(linha),fp);
        printf("%s",linha);
    }
    //fclose(fp);
}
fclose(fp);
```

O código aparentemente funciona mas existe um bug que tenho tentado descobrir mas sem sucesso. Depois de imprimir no output o nome do utilizador e o sexo do utlizador ele imprime também a idade mas entra no loop de onde não sai mais. Eu tentei utilizar o EOF. Já tentei inclusive com `'\0'` mas não consigo descobrir como mandar parar o programa se já não existir mais nada para ler do ficheiro. Alguma sugestão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro que coloque um exemplo de ficheiro com a informação que tem escrita, para que seja mais claro o problema.

Comment: O ficheiro de texto está definido como mostra a imagem. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a função feof(); Para determinar um break no loop; A função verifica quando é o final do arquivo;

```
FILE* fp;
char linha[500];

fp = fopen("Ficheiro Teste.txt","r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Empty Text File!\n");
}
else
{
    while(1)
    {
        fgets(linha,sizeof(linha),fp);
        printf("%s",linha);

      if(feof(fp))
           break;

    }

}
fclose(fp);
```

outra forma é você utilizar a função fgetc() para verificar o EOF

```
 while(fgetc(fp) != EOF)
    {
        fgets(linha,sizeof(linha),fp);
        printf("%s",linha);
    }
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/